# Access content on Azur Blob storage via SharePoint Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, remote-blob-storage

I have a huge data set of some TBs, if I upload it over SharePoint online, it will cost me big dollars.
I was planning to store it on Azure blob storage but looking for solution to get it search or filtered by using SharePoint search!